# ionic2: Header Title not aligning center

Tags: ionic2

[image]

I'm trying to align menu toggle icon to left and title to center of the header. I'm using the below code:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
     <button ion-button menuToggle left>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon> 
     </button> 
     <ion-title>
      Home
     </ion-title> 
 </ion-toolbar>
```

But the title doesn't appear in the centre. please help out. thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello thripthi. Issue fixed ? :D

Answer (score 5):

For android device you need to put this code

Using this code solved this issue for me.

**page.html do this**

```
<ion-header no-border-bottom>

  <ion-navbar color="primary" class="home-nav">
      <ion-title >Dashboard</ion-title>
      <button ion-button menuToggle  >
          <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>   
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

**app.scss file do this**

```
ion-header button, .back-button {
  position: absolute !important;
  z-index: 5;
}


ion-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 90px 1px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: If you do this, you cannot click the back button anymore.

Comment: This is the perfect solution.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add the `text-center` directive to your `ion-title` or `ion-toolbar` or add `class="ion-text-center"`

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
     <button ion-button menuToggle left>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon> 
     </button> 
     <ion-title text-center>
      Home
     </ion-title> 
 </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem can easily be solved by taking out the button from the content flow: set it's position to absolute which leaves the title as only child in it's parent normal flow. It will take up the entire width and get properly centered.

Something like:

```
ion-navbar button {
    position: absolute !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the button within `ion-buttons start`.

Try:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-buttons start><!-- here -->
     <button ion-button menuToggle left>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon> 
     </button> 
     </ion-buttons>
     <ion-title>
      Home
     </ion-title> 
 </ion-toolbar>
```

Toolbar [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#toolbar)

Comment: can you add a screenshot of what it is looking like? otherwise all have to just guess

Comment: i have attached a screenshot

Comment: have you set any additional scss for this?

Comment: have not added scss

Comment: it is working fine here : https://plnkr.co/edit/leAUogT8tqAKa33tYD1X?p=preview maybe you set some padding/margin somewhere?

Comment: the plunker doesn't show menu toggle icon button. i think so it  is because of toggle icon

Answer (score 0):

For ios mobile the title will automatically aligned center all you have to do is for android

```
    <ion-header>

      <ion-navbar color="primary">
         <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle>
          <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon> 
         </button>
         <ion-title>
          Home
         </ion-title> 
     </ion-navbar>
   </ion-header>
```

in your css do this

```
ion-title{
 text-align: center;
}
```

if the above Sass is not applied the try this

```
ion-title.title.title-md {
    text-align: center;
   }
```

Comment: tried not working. title gets aligned to centre if i add an ion-button icon to end

Comment: replace your html code with my code and css then check it should work

Comment: i think i have put my button out of the ion-navbar check my updated one and try that one it will work for sure

Comment: your updated answer result is same. title is aligned as shown in the image i have attached with question

Answer (score 0):

You should use left or right in ion-buttons because start and end doesnt work always

```
    <ion-header>
          <ion-toolbar color="primary">
            <ion-buttons left><!-- here -->
             <button ion-button menuToggle left>
              <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon> 
             </button> 
             </ion-buttons>
             <ion-title>
              Home
             </ion-title> 
         </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use css to center text please try this
html code

```
<ion-title text-center class="comman-title-text-right">Signup</ion-title>
```

add css

```
.comman-title-text-right{
    margin-right: 60px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use mode='ios' on the ion toolbar

using this code solved alignment issue on my android header

here is the corrected code

```
` <ion-toolbar mode='ios' color="primary">
 <button ion-button menuToggle left>
  <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon> 
 </button> 
 <ion-title>
  Home
 </ion-title> 
 </ion-toolbar>`
```